# Changing anonymous author in icml2021.sty

Tags: author

I am trying to use the icml2021 template for one of my classwork, and I figured out the author names are all anonymous. I used the [icml2021.sty](https://github.com/ltl-uva/stroop-template/blob/main/icml2021.sty) styling. In latex, it is not rendering any author name, just anonymous authors,I need to change that, but I am unable to do that.Any kind of help will be appreciated. I saw a if condition as `\isaccepted` and tried to fix by changing its value by 1 to 0 and reverting it back, but it didn't help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I dont think, there is something wrong with my latex code, but with the style file I have given link. because I am calling \icmlauthor and there are already a list of authors exists, but in actual pdf output, it shows 'anonymous authors', but in main.tex, there is no such text, it's  coming from that styling file.hope u understand.